# Assertion error due to file opening

Tags: c, file, fopen, assertion

I was wondering if anyone could spot something glaringly obvious about this, I'm getting an assertion error while trying to open a text file. I've tried a number of different methods to fix this problem with no luck. The code:

```
        FILE *fc;
        fc = fopen("test_text.txt", "w+");
        if(fc == NULL)
        {
              printf("error opening file\n");
        }

       fprintf(fc, "%02x  %02x  %02x  %s", bac_map[0].device_id, bac_map[0].status, bac_map[0].short_addr, bac_map[0].mode);

       for(j = 0; j < object_index; j++)
       {
               fprintf(fc, "             \t %d",bac_map[0].objects_avail[j]);
       }
       fprintf(fc, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\n", bac_map[0].product_id[0]);
       fclose(fc);
```

The error is occurring directly after "fopen" Other methods of opening the file that I have tried:

```
     FILE *fc;
     const char* bac = "test_text.txt";
     fc = fopen(bac, "w+");
     .
     .
     .
```

but I received the same error. This block of code is also contained inside a loop, however I open and close the file in every iteration through the loop. Furthermore, for testing purposes i've placed the same block before and after the loop to try and determine if that was the cause of the problem, but no luck. Also, the struct that I am storing values in also seems to be fine, they print using "printf" just fine. I don't see any correlation between the file opening and structure as it is, but maybe someone else knows if that can cause the issue?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What error does occur? (`perror`)

Comment: whois2.0: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted

Comment: Hm. Is `<stdio.h>` included? On a 64-bit platform, using a C89 compiler and with low warning levels, this could compile and cause such a crash.

Comment: <stdio.h> is included, but i'm not on a 64-bit platform

Comment: Is it possible for other libraries I have included to cause the problem?

Comment: My next guess would be that something is screwed up somewhere else. Writes to invalid memory, a double-`free` or something. Such mistakes can lead to hard-to-track bugs and can show up pretty much everywhere (tools like Valgrind can help in such cases). Can you provide a minimal (but complete!) example? As-is, I don't see anything that could cause a crash.

Comment: I actually tried using "open" instead of "fopen" and this seems to be working. the file is getting created now.

Comment: The `fopen` call shouldn't fail like that. If my guess is correct, that there is a (severe) bug somewhere else, switching to `open` only hides the bug, but doesn't solve it.

Comment: You're right. Switching to "open" is just a band aid. as it turned out, by moving the fopen statement to the top of the program with the rest of my variable declarations, and leaving the rest of the code in its original location, fixed the problem. Seems a little quirky of a fix, but it did solve the problem